# Why is my font-family not working in css?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get any font to work. It was working originally, but I did something and now can't get it back. The error I get in JSFiddle is "Unexpected missing generic font family".

```
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Aldhabi;
}
```

Comment: The generic font family is a fallback font in the event that your preferred font doesn't render for whatever reason (privacy reasons on the user end, errors in your code, etc). https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#value-def-generic-family As far as "not working", you'll need to expand on that. If you don't have the font installed locally and you're not importing it from somewhere, it's not going to render.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family : “You should always include at least one generic family name in a font-family list, since there's no guarantee that any given font is available. This lets the browser select an acceptable fallback font when necessary.”

Answer (score 1):

You need to import it first to your css by using `@import` then you can use it.

```
@import url('http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/aldhabi');

body{
background-color: #ffffff;
font-family: 'Aldhabi', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to use a new **`font-family`**, you have to import it from **[Google-fonts](https://fonts.google.com/)**.

For example, if you want to import **`Poppins`** you have to include this line

```
`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Pacifico&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Roboto+Slab:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;900&display=swap');`
```

in the top of your CSS file.

And then use it where ever you want, Like this:

```
body{
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```